# Regex Conditional termination of a template

Tags: c#, regex

Pattern always begins from a certain key (in example it is **needed beginning**)
Value can be multiline.
Pattern can terminate with one of certain keys (in example it is **ending1** or **ending1**). Termination keys can present both or only one of them in input text. If both, then only first of them is needed.

My regex pattern for this example looks like this: `needed beginning([\S\s]*)(?>ending1|ending2)`

Here is a Regex101 not working [example](https://regex101.com/r/SBNUQG/1)

Second capturing group is totally wrong, and i do not know how to realize this case

Input text can be like this:

```
some 
other
not 
interesting 
text
needed beginning
value       <-- 
can be      <-- this needed to be captured
multiline   <--
ending1
some other values
and other
ending2
some 
other
not 
interesting 
text
```

Or like this:

```
some 
other
not 
interesting 
text
needed beginning
value       <-- 
can be      <-- this needed to be captured
multiline   <--
ending2
some 
other
not 
interesting 
text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for you? 
Updated: https://regex101.com/r/SBNUQG/2

Using regex: needed beginning(.*?)(ending1|ending2)

With option "single line"

Comment: Most part of current logic works with multiline input and adding this flag will lead to the need to recheck and change other parts. Is it possible to do this without adding 'singleline' flag?

Comment: @aleha You can avoid the `s` flag if you use `needed beginning([\s\S]*?)(ending1|ending2)`.

Comment: Single line doesnt mean it has to be on one line, it merely treat it as one line to make the (.) match new line too @aleha